# Flink Error: Accessing a field by position is not supported in name-based field mod

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a `Row` that I am trying to use in Flink like so:

```
Row row = Row.withNames();
jsonNode.fieldNames()
  .forEachRemaining(fieldName -> {
    row.setField(fieldName, jsonNode.get(fieldName));
});

StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.fromCollection(List.of(row));
```

But I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Accessing a field by position is not supported in name-based field mode.
```

I understand that this can be overcome with `Row.withPositions(n)` call. But I can't do that since I want to create the `Row` using `fieldNames`

How do I pass a name-based `Row` to the Flink environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the type information to make this work. If you know the structure of your JSON beforehand, then you can do it the following way:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree("{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\": 30}");
TypeInformation<Row> typeInfo = Types.ROW_NAMED(new String[]{"name", "age"}, Types.STRING, Types.INT);
Row row = Row.withNames();
row.setField("name", root.get("name").asText());
row.setField("age", root.get("age").asInt());
        
env.fromCollection(Collections.singletonList(row), typeInfo).printToErr();
```

However, if the JSON structure is unknown and you need to write a generic solution, it becomes more complicated as you'll need to write a JSON -> Row converter, which maps the JSON types to Flink types.